# ruby on rails unable to find interface that appears to be proplery defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm brand new to ruby on rails and trying to run an application developed by others.  I downloaded it from SVN it running yesterday, but today when I try to run it the first attempt to access the site's home page I get the message:

expected .../app/helpers/interface/table_helper.rb to define Interface::tableHelper.

.../lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:452:in 'load_missing_constant'

This file exists, and properly defines the tableHelper interface.  Since I was able to run the program when I was setting it up yesterday, and others can run it without issue, I assume the problem I'm seeing is caused by an incorrectly set up environment rather then bad code somehow.

Can anyone suggest what I might try to figure out why rails can't seem to detect a properly defined interface?

Comment: Is this the exact error message? I'm expecting the file name to be a ".rb" rather than a ".b"

Comment: I appologize.  I had to type the error message by hand since I couldn't copy and past between two computers.  The interface is in app/helpers not helper.  and it is a .rb file.  I'll update my lazy typing.  I'll also add the preceding error

Comment: Are you getting this error when you use the "rails server" command and then browse to your page or is the site deployed to a webserver?

Comment: I'm using the rails server command (well actually jruby server, but doubt that matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were able to run the program once, perhaps something got screwed up? Have you made any changes to the code?

Alternatively, try stopping and restarting the server.

Also: what's the application? Maybe we can look at the codebase...

Comment: I should also mention that `app/helper` is a nonstandard path. `app/helpers` is what Rails expects.

Comment: I revereted the code back to the original SVN checkout already, and I haven't changed that particular file anyways.  I've tried a stop and restart of the server.  The entire issue started after needing to reboot my computer actually.

Comment: OK. Then let's see the entire exact error message, not just a mangled excerpt as you provided.